# How to Insert the large json file into mysql with php?

Tags: php, mysql, json, parsing

I want to read from large json file and store it in database with php.

I wrote this code for parsing and insert file but the last query does'nt work.

```
public function insert_from_json() {
    $json = '
            [            
            {
            "name": "The Adventurer",
            "year": 1917,
            "country": "USA",
            "durationMinutes": 24,
            "director": "Charles Chaplin"
            },
            {
            "name": "Mest kinematograficheskogo operatora",
            "year": 1912,
            "country": "Russia",
            "durationMinutes": 12,
            "director": "Wladyslaw Starewicz"
            }
            ]';

    $result = json_decode($json);

    $vals = '';
    foreach ($result as $key => $value) {

        if ($value) {
            $vals.="('$value->name','$value->year','$value->country','$value->durationMinutes','$value->director'),";
        }
    }
    $vals = trim($vals, ',');
    $stmt = $this->conn->prepare("INSERT INTO film (name,year,country,durationMinutes,director) VALUES ($vals)");
    $stmt->execute();
    echo 'successfully';
}
```

please help me for make it.

Comment: I feel like this must be covered somewhere.

Comment: What error do you get? Is it generating valid SQL?

Comment: Those parentheses at the very end are superfluous. Remove those, and I suspect it will work - but this doesn't look very secure!

Comment: `"('{$value->name}',` etc...

Comment: Building your query as such defeats the purpose of using prepared statements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
$json = '[            
    {
        "name": "The Adventurer",
        "year": 1917,
        "country": "USA",
        "durationMinutes": 24,
        "director": "Charles Chaplin"
    },
    {
        "name": "Mest kinematograficheskogo operatora",
        "year": 1912,
        "country": "Russia",
        "durationMinutes": 12,
        "director": "Wladyslaw Starewicz"
    }
]';

$result = json_decode($json);

$stmt = $this->conn->prepare("
    INSERT INTO film (name, year, country, durationMinutes, director) 
    VALUES (:name, :year, :country, :durationMinutes, :director)
");

// loop through each object
foreach ($result as $r) {
    // and insert it into the database
    $stmt->execute([
        ':name' => $r->name,
        ':year' => $r->year, 
        ':country' => $r->country, 
        ':durationMinutes' => $r->durationMinutes, 
        ':director' => $r->director
    ]);
}
```

The main difference here is that you are doing multiple inserts instead of one big insert.

Comment: I was very involved in solving this. Thank you so much :)

Answer (score 0):

I've tested this approach on 1.2 GB JSON file with 10 million records and the whole process took about 5mins.

First I tried to convert the JSON file to CSV.
You can't directly read the whole document at once (because of memory limitation). we need to read them line by line.
I suggest [json-machine](https://github.com/halaxa/json-machine) package

```
use JsonMachine\Items as Json;


file_put_contents($csvPath, null);

$csv = fopen($csvPath, 'w');

$items = Json::fromFile($path, [
    'decoder' => new ExtJsonDecoder(true)
]);

foreach ($items as $item) {
    fputcsv($csv, $item);
}

fclose($csv);
```

Then use native MySQL statement called [LOAD DATA](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/load-data.html).

For better readability I was using [laravel-loadfile](https://github.com/ellgreen/laravel-loadfile) package.

```
LoadFile::file($csvPath, true)
    ->into('articles')
    ->replace()
    ->columns(['id', 'name', 'stock'])
    ->fieldsTerminatedBy(',')
    ->fieldsEnclosedBy('"', true)
    ->linesTerminatedBy('\n')
    ->load();
```